# Dose Admob have an api like facebook_ads_api for downloading my ads reports in my own project?

Tags: java, admob

Is there someone who can help me with this problem?

Recently,I need to create a java project which can download the reports from Admob, but I couldn't find the api.

I think google should provide an api for developers like me.

Who can help me ?
Thank you !

Comment: Hmmmmm if a Google search for "admob API" doesn't return anything, I doubt that you'll find the answer in here. Anyways, I'm not sure this type of question is appropiate for the site (just saying).

Comment: @W.Mike  Please look at my answer there is an api, tell me if you need more help and and mark the the answer as answered if it fits your needs

Answer (score 0):

Of Course there is
For accessing admob data use the adsense api: [Adsense - admob api](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/)

You have the reporting api (for ads performance for example) and management api - for creating ads and etc